# Python pip install requires server_hostname

Tags: python, openssl, pip

I finished installing pip on linux, the `pip list` command works. But when using the `pip install` command it got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
    upgrade=self.upgrade,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 305, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 783, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 872, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 473, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 365, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 43, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 518, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 322, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.7-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 254, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 537, in __init__
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I see others with the same problem; it appears related to the OpenSSL library version. No solution yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have Python 2.7.9 or a different version, which would the changes for [issue 22921](http://bugs.python.org/issue22921). Can you update your question to give us the **full** traceback (from the line with `Traceback` on down) to show us where the error might originate from?

Comment: I had the same problem, @MartijnPieters, so I added a full traceback for you. I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Comment: It's solved . um .. when it's caused  i was update the version of openssl . but the error still caused .  then I  re-installed  pip to older version the problem was gone . I don't know why. maybe solutions is install oler pip  or  new version of pip only support new version of  openssl? .

Comment: .my python version 2.7.9  my pip version is 1.5.5

Comment: @DonKirkby: thanks; that implicates `urllib3` in how they use `ssl.wrap_socket()`. I've [poked the project](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/517) about the issue.

Comment: @Mryoun: `pip` includes the [`requests` project](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which in turn uses the [`urllib3` library](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Your older version of pip uses a different version of those packages that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: [pip 6.1.0 is out](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/6.1.0) with a fix.

Answer (score 20):

[pip 6.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/6.1.0) has been released, fixing this issue. You can upgrade with:

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install -U pip
```

to self-upgrade.

---

*Original answer*:

This is caused by a change in Python 2.7.9, which `urllib3` needs to account for. See [issue #543](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/543) for that project. Your OpenSSL libraries do not support SNI, which means `urllib3` won't pass in the host name to the SSL socket wrapper, but Python 2.7.9 expects the hostname to be passed in anyway for different purposes.

`urllib3` is indirectly used by `requests` (see [`requests` issue 2435](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2435)), which in turn is being used by `pip`.

I've opened a [ticket to track this from `pip`'s perspective](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2395).

The underlying issues have been fixed by the project maintainers, and awaiting a new release. You could install the current development version of `pip` if you are impatient:

```
pip install --trusted-host=github.com -U https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/develop.zip
```

This'll install pip-6.1.0.dev0, when 6.1.0 is fully released you can upgrade again with `pip install -U pip` to get the final release from PyPI.

Answer (score 16):

I get the same issue, and find that it can be avoided (pip 6.0.8) in my case as follows

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install <thing>
```

Comment: This also works when installing pip itself: ```python2.7 get-pip.py --trusted-host pypi.python.org --user```

Answer (score 2):

It is related to urllib3.
You can resolve it with urllib3 version 1.25.8.
Download that version of urllib3 manually and install it.

Even though you install thia version, pip will still use its own version.So you have to remove it and replace it.

Usually, installed module is on PythonXX/Lib/site-packages

1. Delete urllib3 in PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor
2. Move  "PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/urllib3" to "PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor".

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and tried the above methods, but not work. I finally find it is because I turn on the VPN. When I turn off the VPN, I can successfully download packages.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue , i tried all of solutions  but when my vpn disconnected it solved

Comment: Hi, could you edit your answer and provide more information what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35077591)