# Error when trying to install python module (beautifulsoup) in CentOS 5.11 Server using pip3.4

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos

I wrote a python3.4 script to fetch some data from an RSS feed that works just as expected. I wanted to create a cronjob to execute the script with my VPS (CentOS 5.11). The server have the regular python and python3.4 installed without problem (i can run python3.4 scripts without problem). The problem is that i need Beautiful Soup installed for python3.4 for my script to work, but when i try to install it, i receive an error from the server:
I use `pip3.4 install beautifulsoup` to install the module.

```
Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
      upgrade=self.upgrade,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 305, in find_requirement
      page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 783, in _get_page
      return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 872, in get_page
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 473, in get
      return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 365, in request
      return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
      r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 43, in send
      resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
      timeout=timeout
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 518, in urlopen
      body=body, headers=headers)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 322, in _make_request
      self._validate_conn(conn)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in _validate_conn
      conn.connect()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
      ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 254, in ssl_wrap_socket
      return context.wrap_socket(sock)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
      _context=self)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 542, in __init__
      raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
  ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I read about the virtual python environments, but i don't know if that will work the way that i wanted to work.
I have root access to the server, i'm doing this through SSH.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

If i use `pip3.4 --trusted-host pypi.python.org install <package_name>` i can upgrade pip3.4 and install urllib3, but when i try to install Beautiful Soup i receive this error:

```
Collecting beautifulsoup
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
  Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-zgrqhr3v/beautifulsoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zgrqhr3v/beautifulsoup/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296476/python-pip-install-requires-server-hostname

Comment: I updated the question. With the method posted in the possible duplicate i was able to upgrade pip3.4 and to install urllib3, but Beautiful Soup is still causing me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing beautifulsoup version 3 which only supports python 2. You need to install version 4 of beautifulsoup which does support python 3.

Do

```
pip3.4 install beautifulsoup4
```