# An issue when downgrade tensorflow from v2.6 to v1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensorflow V2.6 , I need to downgrade it into V1.15. I got an issue when downgrading it as follows:

[image]

and here is the rest of the show error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly be sure to uninstall the previous version of tf you had installed.

Anyway i suggest you to work on your projects in different environments.
This will avoid reinstalling and changing versions of packages needed by the project every time you start a new one, and wont cause problems with other dependencies.

The short way is using the following commands, but i strongly suggest to look up for some tutorial or documentation to fully understand what you are doing.

To install venv:

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv
```

To create a new environment:

```
python3 -m venv {env_name}
```

To activate the environment:

```
source {env_name}/bin/activate
```

for windows:

```
{env_name}\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Finally once you are in the environment (you can see the tag on the left of your terminal) you can safely install all the packages you need and they wont be in conflict with other installations in your machine.

To exit the environment just type:

```
deactivate
```

Every time you need to work in that environment remember to activate it!
Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: I unstalled the prevous tensorflow, but now when I run the first command you provided, (pip3 install --user virtualenv), it gives me the same error I gave in my question .. !!

Comment: Ok, the problem its related to pip itself, or with the python installation.
You should try to reinstall both!

Comment: OK, thank you, I will reinstall everything again

Comment: Perfect, tell me if you can resolve the problem! Otherwise i will point you out to other workarounds.

Comment: I reinstalled the Pycharm, Anacoda, and python 3.9.4 , but when installing the tensorflow using the command pip3 install tensorflow==1.15,   it still gives me the same error shown in my question !!!

Comment: Can you install anything with pip? Or its everything broken?

Comment: I cannot install anything with the pip,  I think the issue is from the pip,  I have unstalled the pip and now trying to install it again but couldn't install it again :) .. When I run python -m pip install -U pip  .. it gives me an error as follows: C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: I installed the pip using easy_install pip     but then when tring install the tensorflow, it gives me the same error shown in the question !!

Comment: Can you try using this command provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319621/9694173):

   pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install -U pip